# Plotting Multiple Argument Function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can i plot

```
f(x,y) = xsin(xy)
```

function on the intervals

```
0 < x < 5 and π < y < 2π
```

Comment: please specify that you want the surface plot or a 3D plot

Answer (score 3):

You could use this for a 3d plot:

```
ezsurf('x*sin(x*y)', [0,5,pi,2*pi])
```

You can also use ezmesh with the same arguments to draw the mesh only (with a transparent surface)